# How to perform index/match excel function equivalent using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am facing the below challenge.

For instance, let the dummy dataframes be,

```
 col1_a | A | B | C
    a   | 1 | 4 | 7
    b   | 2 | 5 | 8
    c   | 3 | 6 | 9
```

Let another dataframe be,

```
 col1_b |col2
    b   | B
    c   | C
    a   | A
```

The output dataframe should be the following,

```
 col1_b | col2 | output
    b   |  B   |  5
    c   |  C   |  9
    a   |  A   |  1
```

My train of thought was to create dictionary(s), in this case, would be,

```
A, B, C

({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9})
```

followed by this function,

```
def func_test1(row):
    if row['col2'] == 'B':
        return test1_df.col1_b.map(B)
    elif row['col2'] == 'C':
        return test1_df.col1_b.map(C)
    elif test1_df['col2'] == 'A':
        return test1_df.col1_b.map(A)
    
test1_df['output'] = test1_df.apply(func_test1, axis=1)
```

I am always getting the following error,

```
 ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 2')
```

Also I think this is not an efficient solution at all.

Are there pandas inbuilt function(s) to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with unpivot `df1` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and `rename` for new column name:

```
df = df2.join(df1.set_index('col1_a').stack().rename('output'), on=['col1_b','col2'])
print (df)
  col1_b col2  output
0      b    B       5
1      c    C       9
2      a    A       1
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), `rename` column and [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1 = (df1.melt('col1_a', var_name='col2', value_name='output')
          .rename(columns={'col1_a':'col1_b'}))
    
df = df2.merge(df1, on=['col1_b','col2'], how='left')
print (df)
  col1_b col2  output
0      b    B       5
1      c    C       9
2      a    A       1
```

Comment: How to join the df's if the situation were other way around? Please have a look at this..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66396910/how-to-lookup-the-data-in-this-situation

Comment: would you happen to know how to answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67017473/how-to-create-a-4-4-5-calendar-using-python

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)

```
df2['output'] = df1.set_index('col1_a').lookup(df2['col1_b'], df2['col2'])
```

if all combinations of df2 are in df1 this works

Comment: ya, you fall to sample data trap. But OK, if same length, same values it working.

Comment: I understand that this is not a general solution but this may be enough. I agree with you, no problem here:) @jezrael