# How to join two dataframe on by looking up values of a column whose values are transformed into different columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have df1 like the following,

```
{'column1': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'DDD', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'EEE', 'EEE', 'FFF', 'GGG', 'FFF', 'GGG', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB'], 'column2': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', nan, nan, 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'], 'column3': ['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'CC', 'CC', 'CC', 'DD', 'DD', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'CC', 'EE', 'EE', 'FF', 'FF', 'FF'], 'column4': ['Jan-20', 'Jan-21', 'Feb-21', 'Feb-20', 'Mar-21', 'Apr-21', 'Jul-21', 'Jul-20', 'Aug-21', 'Sep-21', 'Feb-21', 'Mar-21', 'Oct-21', 'Nov-21', 'Jan-21', 'Apr-21', 'Dec-21', 'Dec-21', 'Dec-20', 'Aug-21', 'Sep-21', 'Feb-21'], 'column5': [123, 214, 32, 12, 23, 2, 43, 14, 2, 113, 5, 6, 324, 13, 1, 123, 3245, 123, 5566, 132, 14, 21]}
```

[image]

On the basis of column1, column2, column3, and column4 (column4 - which is now transformed as columns) I want to populate column5.

The df2 in which I'd want data should look like this,

```
{'column1': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB'], 'column1.5': ['V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], 'column2': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 'column3': ['GG', 'HH', 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF', 'II', 'JJ', 'GG', 'HH', 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF', 'II', 'JJ', 'GG', 'HH', 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF', 'II', 'JJ', 'GG', 'HH', 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF', 'II', 'JJ'], 'Jan-21': [nan, nan, 214.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Feb-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 5.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 21.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, 32.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Mar-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 6.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Apr-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'May-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Jun-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Jul-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Aug-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 132.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Sep-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 14.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Oct-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Nov-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Dec-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]}
```

[image]

df2 already exists in the above format. Would just need to update the months columns and keep data of current year.

How may I approach this problem?

**I want to join these two dataframes while retaining the content of df2 should there be no match.**

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to melt df2 and it will have the same shape as df1?

```
nan = np.NAN

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'column1': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC', 
                 'CCC', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'DDD', 'AAA', 'AAA', 
                 'AAA', 'EEE', 'EEE', 'FFF', 'GGG', 'FFF', 
                 'GGG', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB'], 
     'column2': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 
                 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', nan, nan, 'C', 'D', 'D', 
                 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'], 
     'column3': ['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 
                 'CC', 'CC', 'CC', 'DD', 'DD', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 
                 'CC', 'EE', 'EE', 'FF', 'FF', 'FF'], 
     'column4': ['Jan-20', 'Jan-21', 'Feb-21', 'Feb-20', 'Mar-21', 
                 'Apr-21', 'Jul-21', 'Jul-20', 'Aug-21', 'Sep-21', 
                 'Feb-21', 'Mar-21', 'Oct-21', 'Nov-21', 'Jan-21', 
                 'Apr-21', 'Dec-21', 'Dec-21', 'Dec-20', 'Aug-21', 
                 'Sep-21', 'Feb-21'], 
     'column5': [123, 214, 32, 12, 23, 2, 43, 14, 2, 113, 5, 6, 324, 
                 13, 1, 123, 3245, 123, 5566, 132, 14, 21]}
)
```

[image]

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'column1': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 
                 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 
                 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 
                 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 
                 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 
                 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB'], 
     'column1.5': ['V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 
                   'V', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 
                   'W', 'W', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 
                   'V', 'V', 'V', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 
                   'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], 
     'column2': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 
                 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 
                 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 
                 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 
     'column3': ['GG', 'HH', 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF', 
                 'II', 'JJ', 'GG', 'HH', 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 
                 'EE', 'FF', 'II', 'JJ', 'GG', 'HH', 'AA', 'BB', 
                 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF', 'II', 'JJ', 'GG', 'HH', 
                 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF', 'II', 'JJ'], 
     'Jan-21': [nan, nan, 214.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
     'Feb-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, 5.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 21.0, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, 32.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
     'Mar-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 6.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
     'Apr-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
     'May-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
     'Jun-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
     'Jul-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
     'Aug-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 132.0, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
     'Sep-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 14.0, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
     'Oct-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
     'Nov-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
     'Dec-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
                nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]}
)
```

[image]

As you know df2 it is a pivot table of df1. And you may transform it.

```
melted = df2.melt(
id_vars=['column1', 'column2', 'column3'], 
value_vars=[i for i in df2.columns if '-' in i],
var_name='column4', value_name='column5'
)
```

[image]

Your data may consist different data in column5. Which is right?

```
merged = df1.merge(melted, on=['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4'], how='outer')
```

[image]

As I see It is not right (dataframe is empty):

```
merged[(merged.column5_x != merged.column5_y) # data in column5_x and column5_y is different
       &(merged.column5_x.notnull()) # and not NaN
       &(merged.column5_y.notnull()) # and not NaN
      ]
```

[image]

I think it is not proper way for dropping duplicates but:

```
merged.assign(
    column_5=lambda x: x.column5_x if not x.column5_x.empty else x.column5_y)  \
    .drop(columns=['column5_x', 'column5_y'])
```

Another version:

```
(merged  
    .set_index(['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4']) # move columns to index
    .stack() # move column5_x and column5_y to one column   
    .reset_index() # bring to the initial form
    .drop(columns='level_4') # drop column with names: column5_x, column5_y 
    .drop_duplicates() # what you want 
    .rename(columns={0:'column_5'})) # final step
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but can't we just make a pivot and join df1 and df2 on the basis of common columns with df2 being the left df and df1 the right. I don't understand why we would need to melt to get column 1.5 in df1? because both df1 and df2 exist...just need to make the pivot of df1, drop the months column of df2 and join them on the basis of column1,2,3. I'll be posting my answer shortly.

Comment: also i want the data from df1 in df2, not the other way around but thanks so much for your efforts :)

Comment: First of all, for comparing dataframes (tables) in join operations you need to transform data. If you not to do it you can get duplicated data and unreadable format.



For saving column1.5 you can add it in melted dataframe.

melted = df2.melt(
id_vars=['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column1.5'], 
value_vars=[i for i in df2.columns if '-' in i],
var_name='column4', value_name='column5'
)